# Put elements at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

The red elements below are my divs, the big black rectangle is what the user see at the browser(window), I think that the image is self-explanatory and this is the html and css that produces the current result:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper div{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

What do I need to change or add to make sure the majority of the divs go to the next *line*?

[image]

Comment: i don't know how even to start it...

Comment: Yeah, this question is honestly a rare exception where I'm OK with OP not really knowing where to start or not having much to show. I can't even think of a good way to Google this. But yeah, at the very least you'd need javascript or something serverside to organize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a JSFiddle I created which does this: http://jsfiddle.net/WE2Gj/

I used jQuery in order to dynamically change how many elements were on each line always allowing for the top to have the least amount of elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    adjustWidths();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    adjustWidths();
});

function adjustWidths() {
    cWidth = $('.child').width();
    numDivs = Math.floor($(window).width() / cWidth);
    $('.child').removeClass('clear');
    $('.child:nth-last-child('+numDivs+'n)').addClass('clear');
}
```

Comment: good solution, i didn't wanted to put javascript, but i think that it will be impossible to do this without it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done dynamically (at least not without some custom JS). If you are ok with having a fixed width on your wrapping div then you could force a selected number of elements to sit above the remainder of the elements using the 'nth-child' pseudo selector. But it does require removing the 'float' style and changing to 'display:inline-block'

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    width:500px;
}
span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius:10px
}
span:nth-child(1) {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8N9FJ/)

Comment: i tested your code, but it only work with 6 divs(or span), but if i've more than six?

Comment: You would need to set the items that you want to sit on top to 'display:block;' using the nth-child selector EG span:nth-child(2) {
    display:block;
}